# A phrase meaning without intent or unintentionally?

Tags: idiom-request

I was able to make everyone unintentionally.

I know there's a phrase that basically means "unintentionally", but I can't remember it and I can't find the synonym strangely enough. I think it's an idiom and not just a phrase, but I don't remember it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can google "unintentional synonyms" and get a lot of sites, each of which has multiple synonyms.
You might consider inadvertently, accidentally, unexpectedly.
It would probably be better to search for the adjective forms and apply *-ly* after finding the right expression.
You may also be able to use expressions with prepositions in place of an adverb form, for example, *by chance, by inadvertence*.

You first sentence:
*I was able to make everyone unintentionally.*
doesn't make any sense.